Atcoder ABC350 C問題に関しての質問
https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc350/tasks/abc350_c
atcoderの上記の問題に関しての質問です。自分の回答はできたのですがジャッジで間違い判定を受けました。自分の回答がなぜ間違っているのかがわかりません。わかる方がいましたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。
言語　Python
ジャッジ結果　23個中　13個AC(正解) 10個WA(不正解)
N = int(input())
A = list(map(int,input().split()))
ans=[]
for i in range(N):
  if not(A[i]==(i+1)):
    a=[i+1,A[i]]
    if i+1>A[i]:
      a=[A[i],i+1]
    ans.append(a)
    A[A[i]-1]=A[i]
    A[i]=i+1
print(len(ans))
ran = list(map(lambda i:i+1,range(N)))
for j in ans:
  print("{} {}".format(j[0],j[1]))


直接「どこが間違っているか」は記さないけど
検証できるコードです
先頭部分。2*10**5までということなので, 範囲内の数値を指定
import numpy as np
cnt = 10 # 2*10**5
lst = np.random.permutation(np.arange(cnt) +1)
print(lst)

N = cnt   # int(input())
A = lst.tolist()   # list(map(int,input().split()))

コードの最終部分
for j in ans:
  print("{} {}".format(j[0],j[1]))

  n, m = j[0] -1, j[1] -1
  lst[n],lst[m] = lst[m],lst[n]
  print(lst)

all(n==m +1 for n,m in zip(lst, range(cnt))) # 結果が正しいかどうか
# (lst == np.arange(cnt) +1).all() # NumPyで行うならこちら

5項目程度ならたまに間違う程度で, 10項目になるとかなり間違いが増えます
(コードは作りっぱなしではなく, ソフト開発は検証もメンテナンスもたいてい行うので)
どのようなパターンだと間違った判断になるかを調べてみるとよいかと思います
